# Order of Operations in Calculator

Tags: calculus, functions

When using PEMDAS:
1. Parenthesis
2. Exponents 
3. Multiplication / Division / Modulus
4. Addition / Subtraction

We go by these orders but I get stuck and get a totally crazy answer to what I'm supposed to get. For instance when I'm doing functioning: let's take this formula:

[image]

The question is: *Find the value of x f(x) for x = -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, hence or otherwise, state the domain of the function f.*

Now let's say I take the value -3 and add it into the formula, In the calculator I'd type:

$\large \sqrt({12-3(-3)^2})$

Then I get the answer: **Non-Real Error**

Now my problem is that before I used many this to write this formula taking the PEMDAS to account e.g:

$\large \sqrt{12-3(-3^2)}$

but got no luck. The answer is meant to give me Non Real number but instead gave me a value. Why is it that:

this works: $\large \sqrt({12-3(-3)^2})$ and not this: $\large \sqrt{12-3(-3^2)}$ and in the future how can I make sure to carefully write the values in with the proper formatiing in the calculator i.e. parenthesis etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the problems comes from the fact that your calculator evaluates the following as so:
$$
(-3)^2 = 9 \\
-3^2 = -9
$$

Remember that $\sqrt{12 - 3x^2}$ is only going to have real solutions when $12 - 3x^2 \geq 0$, so for $x \in [-2, 2]$

Comment: Sorry to be pettifogging, but shouldn't that be $12-3x^2\geq 0$ which your interval $x\in[-2,2]$ also suggests?

Comment: Yep sorry, corrected

Comment: Alright, so is there any reason as to why the 12-3x^2 is greater or equal to 0? also what does that x\in[-2,2] mean?

Comment: Have you come across complex numbers before? If you haven't you may have noticed that your calculator has some issues calculating the square root of a negative number, this is because the square root of a negative number isn't a real number. For example, if you square 1 or -1, you get 1, square 2 or -2, you get 4, and it is fairly easy to see that when squaring a real number you never get a negative number, so what on earth do we get if we try to take the square root of a negative number? And $x \in [-2, 2]$ is the same as $-2 \leq x \leq 2$

Comment: Got it! so basically $-2 \leq x \leq 2$ means that -2 will be less than or equal to whatever the value of X is but what does the other part of the X mean? to the right of X? $ \leq 2$ is it just basically saying that positive 2 will be less than or equal to whatever the value of x is?

Comment: $-2 \leq x \leq 2$ means that you want x to be between (inclusive) -2 and 2, perhaps drawing a very simple number line will help you visualise what this means.

Comment: We know this by determining the value we got and through the values we make solution saying that x will be anything between less than or equal to -2 and less than or equal to 2.

Comment: How do we know that it's specifically within the range? is it through our values?